# Trace minimum spanning tree's path

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, depth-first-search

I have a list of connected rooms, I need to visit each room in the list, but I have to record the exact path to traverse the entire graph.

```
1: [2]
2: [1,2,3]
3: [2]
4: [2]
```

```
output: [1,2,3,4]
```

```
expected: [1,2,3,2,4]
```

I've written a Depth First Search that returns a path of [1,2,3,4], what I am looking for is [1,2,3,2,4] I'm unsure of how to keep track of the fact that if I visit 3 , I must go back to 2 before I can move to 4. Sorry if I'm not explaining this well, I'm fairly new to cs.

Here is my dfs function.

```
const dfs = (start, visited = new Set(), path = []) => {
  visited.add(start);

  const connectedRooms = mapObject[start].connections;
  if (visited.size === Object.keys(mapObject).length) {
    return getPathDirections(path);
  } else {
    for (const room of connectedRooms) {
      if (!visited.has(room.ID)) {
        path.push(room.ID)
        visited.add(room.ID);
        dfs(room.ID, visited, path)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a recursive implementation of the DFS search algorithm?

Comment: Also what does your problem have to do with a **minimum** spanning tree?

Comment: I am using a recursive DFS implementation. 

I thought I was looking for the minimum spanning tree, maybe I'm not though? I need to visit each room (could be 1,000s) and build a path that navigates me correctly to each room.

Comment: The minimum spanning tree minimizes the total weight of the edges of the tree. Here you are not minimizing anything (the graph is not even weighted) therefore any spanning tree would do, like the one (implicitly) built by a DFS traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation probably looks somewhat like this:

```
VISITED[1...n] = {false, ..., false}

DFS(v):
   VISITED[v] = true
   Record that v was traversed
   for each neighbor u of v:
      if not VISITED[u]:
         DFS(u)
```

That is you are recording $v$ only when the DFS search starts visiting $v$. You also need to record $v$ when the DFS search comes back to it after having visited one of its children. I.e.:

```
VISITED[1...n] = {false, ..., false}

DFS(v):
   VISITED[v] = true
   Record that v was traversed
   for each neighbor u of v:
      if not VISITED[u]:
         DFS(u)
         Record that v was traversed     //Here we record v, not u!!
```

Comment: Updated my original comment with code snippet.

Comment: My answer still applies. The only difference between your code and my first pseudocode is that you are recording $v$ just before calling DFS(v), while I'm recording it as the first instruction of the inner call.

Comment: I am still missing something, so if it is not visited, I would record v twice? I'm confused.

Comment: If $v$ is not visited then $v$ is recorded $0$ times. If $v$ is visited then $v$ is recorded $\delta(v)+1$ times where $\delta(v)$ is the degree of $v$ in the DFS tree $T$ (i.e., the number of children of $v$ in $T$). I suspect your confusion might come from mixing up $u$ and $v$ in my pseudocode.

Comment: Think I'm equally as confused. I need to do more research, thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: It may help to think recursively, or inductively.  More specifically, think about how, if the recursive DFS on each not-yet-visited child $u$ of $v$ generates a tour $T_v$ of the nodes in the subtree rooted at $v$, you can link those subtrees $T_v$ together to get a tour for $T_u$.